# how to Expand a parent <div> to the height of its children when child div is "transform:scale"

Tags: html, css

i want to have to div-1 height of its child div called div-2 without styling div-1 (we should not add width or height to div-1).

note that div-2 is **scaled** (css -  **transform:scale(10)** ) div.

is this possible?

HTML

```css
.div-1{
  background: #F00;

}

.div-2{
  background: #Ff0;
  opacity:0.5;
  width:50px;
  height: 20px;
  transform:scale(10);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
    <div class="div-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this? it seems a strange requirement